# Incorrect Vertical Spacing in flashcards class

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, flashcards

I am creating a set of flashcards with the flashcards class, designed for Avery 5388 paper. This creates three flashcards per page, but the vertical alignment is incorrect. There should be equal spacing between the top flashcard and the top of the page and the bottom flashcard and the bottom of the page, 1 inch I think, but the document compiles with too much space on the top. When I print the document, the borders of the flashcards do not align with the perforations on the paper. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[grid,avery5388]{flashcards}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\cardfrontstyle{headings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 1}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 2}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 3}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

As far as I can see, the class does not provide for a command with which I can manually alter the padding on the top and bottom. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the paper to know what fits or does not fit but adding `\voffset` as in the line below will shift all the output up by .1in (a similar `\hoffset` can be used to adjust the horizontal position)  so you should be able to fine tune the position to the exact positioning of the output in your printer.

```
\voffset=-.1in
\documentclass[grid,avery5388]{flashcards}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\cardfrontstyle{headings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 1}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 2}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
    \begin{flashcard}{Term 3}
        Example text
    \end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```